# Convert a String with comma separated latitudes and longitudes to a Seq[Coordinate]

Tags: beginner, parsing, scala, coordinate-system

I have a function that receives a `String` like the following:

```
"-10.0 -10.0,10.0 10.0,0.0 0.0"
```

And needs to translate that into a `Seq[Coordinate]` that would look like this:

```
Seq(
    Coordinate(-10.0, -10.0),
    Coordinate( 10.0,  10.0),
    Coordinate(  0.0,   0.0)
)
```

Here is the function that I wrote to achieve this:

```
def toCoordinates(coordinates: String): Seq[Coordinate] = {
  val coordinatesList = coordinates.split(",")
  coordinatesList flatMap { coordinate =>
    coordinate.split("\\s+") match {
      case Array(lat:String, lon:String) => Some(Coordinate(lat.toDouble, lon.toDouble))
      case _                             => None
    }
  }
}
```

I see that if someone sends `"foo bar"` as a coordinate, my code would fail miserably, although I don't see a way to prevent this without some `if` conditions.

Any idea on how I can implement this check while still having functional code? Or any other tips that might be helpful for a Scala newbie.

Comment: [Follow-up question](/q/134859/9357)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of writing `lat.toDouble` and `lon.toDouble`, I would use `s.split("\\s+").map(_.toDouble)` to convert all elements.  The type annotation within the `match` seems excessive to me here.

To discard invalid coordinates such as `"foo bar"`, you would have to catch a `NumberFormatException`.

Note that `split("\\s+")` is not tolerant of spaces after commas.  For example, `" 1.0 2.0".split("\\s+")` would produce `Array("", "1.0", "2.0")`, which would be a three-element array and thus considered invalid.

```
def toCoordinates(ss: String): Seq[Coordinate] = {
  ss.split(",").flatMap { s =>
    try {
      s.split("(?<!^)\\s+").map(_.toDouble) match {
        case Array(lat, lon) => Some(Coordinate(lat, lon))
        case _               => None       
      }
    } catch {
      case e: NumberFormatException => None
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Also you can write more human-readable and understandable algorithm with the help of extractors and method `collect`:

```
val Coord = """(.+?)\s+(.+)""".r

object Double { def unapply(s: String) = Try(s.toDouble).toOption }

def parseCoordinates(input: String): Seq[Coordinate] =
  input.split(',') collect {
    case Coord(Double(lat), Double(lan)) => Coordinate(lat, lan)
  }
```

Comment: what does that `.r` do? The one on the definition of `Coord`

Comment: Method `.r` creates regular expression (instance of Regex class). `"abc".r` is equivalent to `new Regex("abc")`. See description and usage [here](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/#scala.util.matching.Regex).