# Parsing latitude and longitude, using Try[T] to ignore errors

Tags: beginner, parsing, error-handling, scala, coordinate-system

I wrote [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/134780/convert-a-string-with-comma-separated-latitudes-and-longitudes-to-a-seqcoordina/) question asking about how to implement my error handling while still maintaining functional code and based on [**200_success's**](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/134786/111332) very interesting note on the spaces, I decided to `trim()` the `String` first, but I wanted to avoid using `try/catch` blocks and use more of Scala's specific features, so I thought of a solution with the `Try` type:

```
private def tryParseDouble(value: String) = Try(value.toDouble)

def toCoordinates(coordinates: String): Seq[Coordinate] = {
  val coordinatesList = coordinates.split(",")
  coordinatesList flatMap { coordinate =>
    coordinate.trim().split("\\s+").map(tryParseDouble) match {
      case Array(Success(lat), Success(lon)) => Some(Coordinate(lat, lon))
      case _                                 => None
    }
  }
}
```

Would this be an acceptable way to implement error handling? Or am I overthinking this and a simple `try/catch` would be just as good?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks pretty good to me.

`Try` is preferable over `try/catch` since it gives more options on how to process the `Failure` case.  In particular, the fact that `Try` can be `flatMap`'d means that you an build a for-comprehension to cover the processing and essentially abort on the first failure.

```scala
for {
  x <- Try("1".toInt)
  y <- Try("a".toInt)
  z <- Try("3".toInt)  // never invoked due to above error
} yield x + y + z

// returns: Failure(java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "a")
```

For parsing a `String` to an `Int` it doesn't matter as much, but if the body of the `Try` is expensive then some of that cost can be avoided.

Depending on the context you're working in then it might behoove you to capture and log the `Failure`s as well; for some one-off code silently ignoring the failures might be fine, but in an application it can save a lot of heartache when dirty data inevitably makes its way in.